# Can a git alias have a period (.) in its name?

Tags: git, alias

I find myself often typing `git st .` (where `st` is already aliased to `status`) to get the status of just the current directory's files.

I often mistype that as `git st.` which of course doesn't get recognized.

I'd love to be able to alias `st.` but it doesn't seem like I can. If I add `st. = status .` to my .gitconfig aliases, I get a `fatal: bad config file` error on git invocations.

Is it possible to create an alias with a period in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible (without changing and recompiling Git itself). From the [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) documentation:

> The variable names are case-insensitive, allow only alphanumeric characters and `-`, and must start with an alphabetic character.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I wasn't sure if aliases were a special case, or if their names could be escaped somehow.

Answer (score 5):

No; if you look at [`config.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/config.c#L1253-L1272), it must be alphanumeric.

```
/*
 * Validate the key and while at it, lower case it for matching.
 */
*store_key = xmalloc(strlen(key) + 1);

dot = 0;
for (i = 0; key[i]; i++) {
    unsigned char c = key[i];
    if (c == '.')
        dot = 1;
    /* Leave the extended basename untouched.. */
    if (!dot || i > baselen) {
        if (!iskeychar(c) ||
            (i == baselen + 1 && !isalpha(c))) {
            error("invalid key: %s", key);
            goto out_free_ret_1;
        }
        c = tolower(c);
    } else if (c == '\n') {
        error("invalid key (newline): %s", key);
        goto out_free_ret_1;
    }
    (*store_key)[i] = c;
}
(*store_key)[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can only pick one answer!